# where en laravel con with

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Como puedo utilizar where para filtrar en consultas with que relacionan múltiples tablas.

```
$a = App\A::with(['bs', 'bs.cs', 'bs.cs.ds'])->get();
```

como puedo hacer que 'bs.cs.ds' atributoX = 40 y 'bs.cs' atributoY = true

Answer (score 1):

Te saludo y te comento con el ejemplo siguiente; que cuando haces eagger loading y necesitas establecer condiciones, lo hagas de la siguiente manera

```
$users = App\Category::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('posts_title', 'like', '%backend%')
          ->where('posts_status', 1);
}])->get();
```

> Como puedes notar en el arreglo asociativo paso primero el nombre del
>   método al que hago referencia en mi ejemplo(posts), posterior creo una
>   función anónima que recibe como parámetro a $query la cual me va a
>   permitir acceder a los métodos where que yo requiera por medio del
>   operador `->` como observas puedo declarar tantos como necesite y al
>   final coloco `get();`

Te lo coloco con un ejemplo que espero te sirva de referencia para adaptarlo a tus necesidades

Para mayor referencia, favor de visitar [este enlace](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)